# Node server.js needs bearer token

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, serverside-javascript, get-request

I would like your help on this matter and if my suspicions are correct, I will just be needing a waypoint as to where to insert which code.

I've got a working get request:

```
const https = require ('https')

https
    .get('https://app.tmetric.com/api/reports/summary/projects?reportParams.billable=true&reportParams.accountId=110649&reportParams.startDate=01-01-2020&reportParams.endDate=01-31-2020', resp => {
        let data = ''

        resp.on('data', chunk => {
            data += chunk
        })

        resp.on('end', () => {
            let timeData = JSON.parse(data)
            console.log(timeData)
        })
     })
```

I know I have to put somewhere something like a setHeaders('Authorization', 'Bearer [token]') but where?
Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: var options = {
  'method': 'GET',
  'hostname': 'https://app.tmetric.com/api/reports/summary/projects?reportParams.billable=true&reportParams.accountId=110649&reportParams.startDate=01-01-2020&reportParams.endDate=01-31-2020',
  'headers': {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer token'
  },
  'maxRedirects': 20
};

https.request(options, function (res) { // play here})

Answer (score 1):

According https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_get_options_callback , you can pass options to the get function.

```
const options = {
    headers: {
        Authorization: "....."
    }
}

https.get('https://app.tmetric.com/api/reports/summary/projects?reportParams.billable=true&reportParams.accountId=110649&reportParams.startDate=01-01-2020&reportParams.endDate=01-31-2020'', options, resp => {
    let data = ''

    resp.on('data', chunk => {
        data += chunk
    })

    resp.on('end', () => {
        let timeData = JSON.parse(data)
        console.log(timeData)
    })
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a reference for you

```
const https = require('https');

const options = {
  hostname: 'httpbin.org',
  path: '/get',
  headers: {
    Authorization: 'authKey',
  },
};

https.get(options, (response) => {
  var result = '';
  response.on('data', function (chunk) {
    data += chunk;
  });

  response.on('end', function () {
    let timeData = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(timeData);
  });
});
```